# Weblogic NegotiateIdentityAsserter and user principal name

Tags: weblogic, kerberos, principal

My web application uses Kerberos authentication. I set NegotiateIdentityAsserter and LDAP Authentication Provider. Everything works fine if sAMAccountName is user for user lookup. Unfortunately in tagret environment this attribute is not unique. I need to identify user by his UPN (user principal name).

Is there a way how to achieve it?

My configuration is

Weblogic 10.3.5
Java 1.6

---

login.config:

```
myrealm { 
weblogic.security.auth.login.UsernamePasswordLoginModule required debug=true;
}; 

com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
     com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
     principal="HTTP/ceprwlvyv.dsmsp.local@DSMSP.LOCAL"
     refreshKrb5Config=true
     useKeyTab=true
     keyTab="c:/ccaapl/security/ceprwlvyv_ktpass.keytab"
     storeKey=true
     debug=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.accept {
     com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
     principal="HTTP/ceprwlvyv.dsmsp.local@DSMSP.LOCAL"
     refreshKrb5Config=true
     useKeyTab=true
     keyTab="c:/ccaapl/security/ceprwlvyv_ktpass.keytab"
     storeKey=true
     debug=true;

};

com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept {
     com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
     principal="HTTP/ceprwlvyv.dsmsp.local@DSMSP.LOCAL"
     refreshKrb5Config=true
     useKeyTab=true
     keyTab="c:/ccaapl/security/ceprwlvyv_ktpass.keytab"
     storeKey=true
     debug=true;

};
```

---

krb5.ini:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = DSMSP.LOCAL
kdc_timesync = 1
ccache_type = 4
ticket_lifetime = 600
clockskew = 1200
dns_lookup_kdc = true

[realms]
DSMSP.LOCAL = {
kdc = DSDC.dsmsp.local
}

[appdefaults]
autologin = true
forward = true
forwardable = true
encrypt = true
```

Thanks in advance!

Petr

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is misleading. Why do you mix Kerberos auth and LDAP auth? You need Kerberos auth only.
After a sucessfully login, you'll be given the user's UPN. Search with that in your AD in the field: userPrincipalName.
This is how I do it.
You question is not precise enough. You are mixing up authentication and user lookup.

Comment: You don't get UPN from Kerberos ticket. What you will get is SAM@realm (domain). So you then have to search for UPN in LDAP by searching for SAM within parsed search base DN in multidomain forest, because SAM is not necessarily unique in forest (it is only good practise).